# How to determine the correct way to pass the struct parameters in arm64 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, struct, arm64, apple-silicon

Suppose I have this function that has many struct parameters (example from [Raylib](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h)):

```
void DrawTexturePro(Texture texture, Rectangle source, Rectangle dest, Vector2 origin, float rotation, Color tint) {
    // do something with these
}
```

full `test.c`:

```
// Texture, tex data stored in GPU memory (VRAM)
typedef struct Texture {
    unsigned int id;        // OpenGL texture id
    int width;              // Texture base width
    int height;             // Texture base height
    int mipmaps;            // Mipmap levels, 1 by default
    int format;             // Data format (PixelFormat type)
} Texture;
// Rectangle, 4 components
typedef struct Rectangle {
    float x;                // Rectangle top-left corner position x
    float y;                // Rectangle top-left corner position y
    float width;            // Rectangle width
    float height;           // Rectangle height
} Rectangle;
// Vector2, 2 components
typedef struct Vector2 {
    float x;                // Vector x component
    float y;                // Vector y component
} Vector2;
// Color, 4 components, R8G8B8A8 (32bit)
typedef struct Color {
    unsigned char r;        // Color red value
    unsigned char g;        // Color green value
    unsigned char b;        // Color blue value
    unsigned char a;        // Color alpha value
} Color;

void DrawTexturePro(Texture texture, Rectangle source, Rectangle dest, Vector2 origin, float rotation, Color tint) {
    // do something with these
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Texture tex = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    Rectangle rec = { 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
    Vector2 vec = { 0.4f, 0.5f};
    Color color = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    DrawTexturePro(tex, rec, rec, vec, 0.6f, color);
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to disassemble this code, it is very interesting to see that:

```
_DrawTexturePro:                        ; @DrawTexturePro
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    sub sp, sp, #64
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
    ldr w10, [sp, #64]
    ldr w9, [sp, #68]
    ldr w8, [sp, #72]
    str s0, [sp, #48]
    str s1, [sp, #52]
    str s2, [sp, #56]
    str s3, [sp, #60]
    str s4, [sp, #32]
    str s5, [sp, #36]
    str s6, [sp, #40]
    str s7, [sp, #44]
    str w10, [sp, #24]
    str w9, [sp, #28]
    str x1, [sp, #8]
    ldr w9, [sp, #8]
    str w9, [sp, #20]
    str w8, [sp, #4]
    add sp, sp, #64
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

full disassembly:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 13, 0 sdk_version 13, 1
    .globl  _DrawTexturePro                 ; -- Begin function DrawTexturePro
    .p2align    2
_DrawTexturePro:                        ; @DrawTexturePro
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    sub sp, sp, #64
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 64
    ldr w10, [sp, #64]
    ldr w9, [sp, #68]
    ldr w8, [sp, #72]
    str s0, [sp, #48]
    str s1, [sp, #52]
    str s2, [sp, #56]
    str s3, [sp, #60]
    str s4, [sp, #32]
    str s5, [sp, #36]
    str s6, [sp, #40]
    str s7, [sp, #44]
    str w10, [sp, #24]
    str w9, [sp, #28]
    str x1, [sp, #8]
    ldr w9, [sp, #8]
    str w9, [sp, #20]
    str w8, [sp, #4]
    add sp, sp, #64
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
    .globl  _main                           ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align    2
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    sub sp, sp, #144
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #128]            ; 16-byte Folded Spill
    add x29, sp, #128
    .cfi_def_cfa w29, 16
    .cfi_offset w30, -8
    .cfi_offset w29, -16
    mov w8, #0
    str w8, [sp, #20]                   ; 4-byte Folded Spill
    stur    wzr, [x29, #-4]
    stur    w0, [x29, #-8]
    stur    x1, [x29, #-16]
    adrp    x8, l___const.main.tex@PAGE
    add x8, x8, l___const.main.tex@PAGEOFF
    ldr q0, [x8]
    stur    q0, [x29, #-48]
    ldr w8, [x8, #16]
    stur    w8, [x29, #-32]
    adrp    x8, l___const.main.rec@PAGE
    add x8, x8, l___const.main.rec@PAGEOFF
    ldr q0, [x8]
    str q0, [sp, #64]
    adrp    x8, l___const.main.vec@PAGE
    add x8, x8, l___const.main.vec@PAGEOFF
    ldr x8, [x8]
    str x8, [sp, #56]
    adrp    x8, l___const.main.color@PAGE
    add x8, x8, l___const.main.color@PAGEOFF
    ldr w8, [x8]
    str w8, [sp, #52]
    ldur    q0, [x29, #-48]
    add x0, sp, #32
    str q0, [sp, #32]
    ldur    w8, [x29, #-32]
    str w8, [sp, #48]
    ldr s0, [sp, #64]
    ldr s1, [sp, #68]
    ldr s2, [sp, #72]
    ldr s3, [sp, #76]
    ldr s4, [sp, #64]
    ldr s5, [sp, #68]
    ldr s6, [sp, #72]
    ldr s7, [sp, #76]
    ldr w10, [sp, #56]
    ldr w9, [sp, #60]
    ldr w8, [sp, #52]
    str w8, [sp, #24]
    ldr x1, [sp, #24]
    mov x8, sp
    str w10, [x8]
    str w9, [x8, #4]
    mov w9, #39322
    movk    w9, #16153, lsl #16
    fmov    s16, w9
    str s16, [x8, #8]
    bl  _DrawTexturePro
    ldr w0, [sp, #20]                   ; 4-byte Folded Reload
    ldp x29, x30, [sp, #128]            ; 16-byte Folded Reload
    add sp, sp, #144
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__const
    .p2align    2                               ; @__const.main.tex
l___const.main.tex:
    .long   0                               ; 0x0
    .long   1                               ; 0x1
    .long   2                               ; 0x2
    .long   3                               ; 0x3
    .long   4                               ; 0x4

    .section    __TEXT,__literal16,16byte_literals
    .p2align    2                               ; @__const.main.rec
l___const.main.rec:
    .long   0x00000000                      ; float 0
    .long   0x3dcccccd                      ; float 0.100000001
    .long   0x3e4ccccd                      ; float 0.200000003
    .long   0x3e99999a                      ; float 0.300000012

    .section    __TEXT,__literal8,8byte_literals
    .p2align    2                               ; @__const.main.vec
l___const.main.vec:
    .long   0x3ecccccd                      ; float 0.400000006
    .long   0x3f000000                      ; float 0.5

    .section    __TEXT,__literal4,4byte_literals
l___const.main.color:                   ; @__const.main.color
    .byte   97                              ; 0x61
    .byte   98                              ; 0x62
    .byte   99                              ; 0x63
    .byte   100                             ; 0x64
```

Looks like the params are passed so that *parts of the structs are in multiple registers*.
According to [AArch64 parameter passing rules](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#parameter-passing-rules) if the Composite Type (in this case the struct?) is larger than 16 bytes, then rules `B.4` dictates that it will be copied to allocated memory and passed as an address.

> If the argument type is a Composite Type that is larger than 16 bytes, then the argument is copied to memory allocated by the caller and the argument is replaced by a pointer to the copy.

<s>**However**, `Rectangle` is a struct comprised of 4 float values, making its size at least 32 bytes. Why then is its members passed to `s0-s3` and `s4-s7` (line 71 to 79 of my disassembly) instead of being just a single address passed in a register (and btw if that is the case, which register set will this address be used in, the regular or the floating point registers?)</s>

`Rectangle`'s size is only 16 bytes since each IEEE-754 float is 4 bytes. The compiler is correct. (thanks @Siguza)

My question is two fold:

1. **If I look at the C function declaration, how do I tell which way the compiler would like me to pass parameters to it using AArch64 assembly?** (for example, passing an address of the struct on one register vs passing the truct's values onto multiple registers)
2. **did the [AArch64 procedure call standard](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#the-base-procedure-call-standard) address it somehow and I'm just not seeing it, or is this really not defined?**

EDIT: Question clarified following @httpdigest's pointer in the comment.

EDIT2: Question error fixed following @Siguza's comment.

Comment: @httpdigest: Thank you for the pointer, and I tried to read that section again. However, it doesn't look right: it claims that Composite Types larger than 16 bytes will be passed by reference, but `Rectangle` is definitely larger than 16 bytes (4 floats each 8 bytes = 32 bytes) but it is still passed into s0 - s7 for some reason. I'll update my question to add that part. Honestly it's contradictory to what the output of the compiler is.

Comment: @stanle float is 4 bytes.

Comment: Nevertheless though, AAPCS64 is **not** the ABI used by Darwin. Some of the differences are outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms), but I'm not convinced that this is a complete list.

Comment: @Siguza: AHA! That's where I'm wrong. I typed "single precision (IEEE 754) how many bytes" into google and got 8 bytes as the answer and just didn't think enough to read into it. Turns out float is 4 bytes and double is 8 bytes lol. Thank you! that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @httpdigest and @Siguza I think the answer to my question is as follow:

**The parameter passing rules for aarch64 can be found [here](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#parameter-passing-rules). Darwin's rules that diverge from the standard can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms).**

**To determine the correct way of passing the parameter when you are looking at a function:**

1. Know the size of your param. Check if the param is larger than 16 bytes. If it is, then allocate memory, copy it to said memory and pass a pointer to the first available general register.
2. If the param is smaller than 16 bytes and is not a composite type, depending on which machine type it is (reference [here](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#arm-c-and-c-language-mappings)) pass it to either the general purpose registers (x0-x7 for example) or the floating point registers (q0-q7 for example).
3. If the param is a struct smaller than 16 bytes, then each of its elements will be loaded onto the registers one by one (for example, line 70-73 in my disassembly shows how `Rectangle` is passed as four floats on s0 to s3).

Thank you very much everyone! This is making more sense to me now.